# Simple Mac video converter app

Tags: osx, video, media-converter

I'm looking for a simple app to convert various video formats into something iTunes will accept (MP4s work, I don't know if there are others).

Requirements:

- clean, simple UI without ads
- not spyware - for some reason a lot of video converters look really shady
- available on the Mac App Store or other trusted source
- would be nice if it could add to iTunes automatically
- reasonable price (under 20$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [iFlicks 2](http://www.iflicksapp.com/en) which fits most requirements, it's just a bit on the expensive side. They're also available through a third-party App Store which has a 30 day trial period.

It supports watching a folder which works great for downloads - point it to your download folder and as soon as the file finishes downloading it'll be in your iTunes library - it can even delete the original file afterwards to avoid wasting disk space (as iTunes copies it into its own folder upon import).

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely check out [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/)

[image]

I use this application all the time to convert videos for Apple TV and iTunes.  Open-source and free for download

Comment: I've tried it but found it relatively hard to use (the last thing I want after an exhausting day of work is fiddling with video compression settings). I was looking for a more user-friendly experience that automatically chooses sane defaults and hides the complexity away from the user.

Comment: You don't need to fiddle around with any settings… If you dig a little deeper, you will see that there are a bunch of presets to choose from. Just select any of the presets and you're good to go. I choose the preset for Apple TV 4